# Button unselectable after UIView animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

in my app i have a UIView with a UIButton Subview. In the viewDidLoad i'm hiding a custom view. when the user click a certain button, the view should appear with the button. it's working fine but the button is no more selectable. i can't interact with it any more after the animation. what could be wrong? here is the code.
ViewDidLoad:

```
view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-150, 0, 150, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:view.frame];
imageView.image = effectImage;
[view addSubview:imageView];
[self.view addSubview:view];

UIButton *remove = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 170, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
    [remove setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:remove];
```

Animation in another method:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(150, 0, 150, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
    }];
```

i personally don't find anything wrong. any help?

Comment: Do you addTarget to the remove button?  If not, no clicks will work.

Comment: ya i did that. not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UIView` and `UIButton` seem to overlap by 20 pixels since the button is 170 wide and the view is placed at x coord of 150. So you probably need to bring the button to the front.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:remove];
```

or

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(150, 0, 150, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:view];
}];
```